# Replace a string word with empty space with js

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
var string = "Deluxe 3 Bed  Private"
```

and the following code to replace the "Private" word with an empty space:

```
var rooms = ["Basic", "Standard", "Superior", "Deluxe", "Private"];
//var room = "room";
vwo_$(document).ready(function(){

  WRI.eventBus.on('ui:microsite:availabilityStore:refresh', function(){
    var roomName = $(".roomnamelink");
    roomName.each(function(){
      for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        var pattern = "[^\s]" + rooms[i];
        var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        string = string .replace(regex, " ");
      }
    });
  })
```

but my regex is probably wrong.

If the word "Private" is found in the string I want that replaced with an empty space.

```
var string = "Deluxe 3 Bed"
```

Comment: you can test the regex online. https://regex101.com/

Comment: you want to replace each word of the array if found with a space?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t3uor52n/ the regex works correctly

Comment: I want to replace any of the words found in the rooms array with an empty space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace any of the words found in the rooms array with an empty space
>   you can use one regex for all the possible words

```
var regex = /\b(Basic|Standard|Superior|Deluxe|Private)\b/gi
```

and the use it with `String#replace` method

```
var string = "Deluxe 3 Bed  Private"
string.replace(regex, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could search for white space and the word, you want to replace.

```js
var re = /[\s]*?private/gi,
    str = 'Deluxe 3 Bed  Private',
    subst = ''; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
console.log('#' + result + '#');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using very simple code like below:

```
 var string = "Deluxe 3 Bed  Private"
 //checking whether private is in String or not.

 if (wordInString(string, 'Private')) 
   { 
    string = string.replace('Private', ' ');
   }
   alert(string);

        function wordInString(s, word) {
            return new RegExp('\\b' + word + '\\b', 'i').test(s);
        }
```

that's all.. :)